# Using dataset as a parameter in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, dataset

Under is my method to fill a dataset, when i run it i get this exception:
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**  but the same working fine in vb.net

```
public void LoadTxt(DataSet Ds, String qry)
{
    try
    {
        Ds.Tables.Clear();
        Da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
        Da.Fill(Ds);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please help anyone actually i'm switching towards C# from VB.NET

Comment: Set a [Breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx) and check what is null. There is no difference between breakpoints in C# and VB.Net

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks it worked. I was just passing a silly null :)